# WebDAV ACL: Setting read permission on folder for principal

Tags: acl, webdav, caldav

I am attempting to give another principal read-permission to a WebDAV-folder I own. According to [RFC3744](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc3744.html) this should be possible using PROPPATCH, but only examples of PROPFIND are listed.

The only example I find is an example of how *not* to set owner (read-only property):

```
<propertyupdate xmlns="DAV:">
  <set>
    <prop>
      <owner>
        <href>principal_uri</href>
      </owner>
    </prop>
  </set>
</propertyupdate>
```

From that I've deduced this (failing) PROPPATCH:

```
<propertyupdate xmlns="DAV:">
  <set>
    <prop>
      <acl>
        <ace>
          <principal>
            <href>principal_uri</href>
          </principal>
          <grant>
            <privilege>
              <read/>
            </privilege>
          </grant>
        </ace>
      </acl>
    </prop>
  </set>
</propertyupdate>
```

I am doing this against Bedework 3.8 Calendar Server. It answers correctly to ACL-queries. The PROPPATCH above is responded with a 404 Not Found. Request is towards a valid URL.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Sincerely, Christian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update ACL's, you can't use `PROPPATCH`. You must use the `ACL` http method instead.